# Modifing a pandas row after iterating on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm studing pandas and I'm trying to iterate on rows and make some calculations on rows.

I have a DataFrame with a number of columns that is not know upfront. I have some symbols and if the symbol name is 'AAPL' I have one column that is named 'AAPL', one that is named 'S_AAPL', one that is named 'V_AAPL'.

```
for  pd_prices_index, pd_prices_row in pd_price.iterrows():
    date = pd_prices_index
    for idx, row in pd_orders.iterrows():
        if row['trade_dates'] == date:
        print 'Matching found in date: ' + str(date)
        #
        #Updating the orders
        #
        order_type = row['order'].upper()
        pd_price.ORDER_TYPE[pd_prices_index] = order_type
        symbol_name = row['symbol'].upper()
        pd_price.SYMBOL[pd_prices_index] = symbol_name
        if order_type == 'BUY':
            size = row['size']
        if order_type == 'SELL':
            size = -row['size'] 
        pd_price.QUANTITY[pd_prices_index] = size
        #
        #Updating the symbols values
        #
        s_symbol = 'S_'+symbol_name
        pd_price.xs(pd_prices_index)[s_symbol] = size
```

The last istruction is not updating the DataFrame pd_price, as of course it creates a copy.

What is the correct approach to have updated with the value in size the "cell" with index pd_prices_index and column matching the value of the variable s_symbol?

If I try:

```
pd_price.xs(pd_prices_index, copy = False)[s_symbol]= size
```

I have this message back:

```
raise Exception('cannot get view of mixed-type or '
Exception: cannot get view of mixed-type or non-consolidated DataFrame
```

I'm using pandas on a macos 10.6.8

The version of pandas is 0.7.3

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `ix` instead of `xs` (e.g., `pd_price.ix[pd_prices_index, s_symbol] = size`)?

Comment: BrenBarn, it works now. I'll check pandas documentation to understand better the behaviour of .ix. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way you can avoid the nested loops in your code and make a pure pandas solution.